# Sharing an external hard drive connected to PC via USB to other devices

Tags: windows, networking, homegroup

I have a desktop PC running Windows 7 Home. I have an external hard drive connected via USB to that PC.

I would like to be able to share that external hard drive with other computers. For instance I have a Surface RT and ideally I would like to be able to browse the external hard drive from my Surface, play videos, view images, be able to move files from the Surface hard drive to the external hard drive

The main desktop PC has no login (it has an admin user but no password set) so I am unsure on how to go about this.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

I have tried to join the HomeGroup via the Surface but after a couple of minutes of trying it says 'Windows no longer detects a homegroup on this network.'

Comment: @cybernard I tried that. I get error message '\\COMP1 is not accessible. You might not have permissions to use this network resource. Contact the admin of the server to find out if you have access permissions. The server service is not started'

Comment: It could be a few things but generally ime that would indicate that Windows Firewall is blocking.  Go to Start button, type 'firewall' and choose the 'allow a program through windows firewall' option.  Check that 'File and Printer Sharing' is allowed (checked) for the appropriate network/zone.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes all PC are on the same network with no firewalls or etc block it. First, right click the drive letter

```
Share with -> Advanced sharing
```

Then again:

```
Advanced sharing
```

Then:

```
Share this folder
```

Setup the permission you want and it should be accessible:

```
\\ComputerName\Sharename
```

On the computers and your should have access.